# Negative lookahead regex without whitespace in between

Tags: regex

The regex below matches all three examples below.

```
(?!\d+)(bn)

325bn
325 bn
424bn
```

I only want to match

```
325bn
424bn
```

More specifically, I only want to match the `bn` in front of the digits

Comment: How are you using the regex? Note your pattern will always match any `bn` as it is not equal to a digit (the lookahead restricts `bn` in such a way that it cannot match 1 or more digits pattern). `(?!\d+)(bn)` = `(bn)`. `\d+bn` seems enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why your regex is wrong

Your regex will match any `bn` no matter what. Since the lookahead is placed before the `(bn)` it will always evaluates to `true` (Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew).

However even in the right position, `(bn)(?!\d+)` will match any `bn` that is not followed by digits ([`positive/negative lookarounds`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)). 
So all of these will be matched:

```
sj bn bn bn bn bn
somethingbn
```

This is not what you want.

### Solution

As far as I understand you only need to match `bn` that is placed after some digits. Why don't you just go with:

```
\d+(bn)
```

#### Output

```
325bn ---> Match
325 bn
424bn ---> Match

sj bn bn bn bn bn
somethingbn
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lY2KvW/1)

### Solution with positive lookbehind

As @revo mentioned, it might be helpful to have a solution using lookaround to have an idea on how it works.

```
(?<=\d)bn
```

This is a `positive lookbehind`. This tells *the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there*.

Comment: Your *Your regex will also match any bn that is not followed by digits* explanation is not correct because of the lookahead location in the pattern. The lookahead in the original pattern is redundant as it always evaluates to *true*.

Comment: Since OP mixed up lookarounds, it would be helpful to tell them that they had to use a lookbehind instead (if supported): `(?<=\d)bn`

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data and expected matches, it seems you indeed wanted to use positive look behind but rather you ended up using negative look ahead incorrectly. And also, quantified `\d+` look behinds are rarely supported (supported in .NET).

As you wrote, you more specifically wanted to only match the `bn` preceded by digit, you can change your regex to this,

```
(?<=\d)bn\b
```

This ensures a `bn` is matched if it is preceded by a digit and `\b` ensures `bn` doesn't match in larger word which starts with `bn`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bMTw3M/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `(?!\d+)(bn)` reads as assert what is directly on the right is not 1+ digits. Which will be true because it is followed by `bn`

You could use a capturing group with a word boundary instead of a positive lookahead:

```
\b\d+(bn)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5YA1E/1)

If there should be preceded by either the start of the string or a whitespace char `(?:\s|^)` and it can only be followed by not a non whitespace char `(?!\S)`, you could use:

```
(?:\s|^)\d+(bn)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5YA1E/2)

Answer (score 0):

> More specifically, I only want to match the `bn` in front of the digits

Order matters, and it should be *positive* lookahead then.

`(bn)(?=\d+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFu4JG/1)